# Prototypal Inheritance and setting values

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have this code.

```
Animal = function(age)
{
    Animal.prototype.age = age;
};
Animal.prototype.constructor = Animal;

Animal.prototype.Walk = function()
{
    console.log("Animal Walking");
};


Pet = function(age, name)
{
    Pet.prototype.name = name;
};
Pet.prototype.constructor = Pet;
Pet.prototype = Object.create(new Animal());


Pet.prototype.DoTricks = function()
{
    console.log(this.name + " is doing tricks!");
};

var pet = new Pet(5, "Barney");

console.log(pet);
```

All Animals have an age and can walk.
Pet Inherits Animal through its prototype.
Pets have names and can do tricks, they also have an age and can walk.

How can I organise my code to achieve this behaviour? At the moment I can make it so Pets can walk but their age is left undefined since I cannot pass its age through the constructor.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Don't modify the `prototype` within a constructor. The `prototype` is shared among all instances while the constructor should then modify the individual instance (`this`).

Comment: Tip: the `Pet.prototype.constructor = Pet;` line does nothing when it’s *before* the part where you set the prototype. Also, `Pet = function(age, name)` is undeclared and you should use `function Pet(age, name)` (which also gives it a name and works in strict mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass arguments from a constructor to its *base*, you can execute the base constructor with [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var Pet = function (age, name) {
    Animal.call(this, age);
    // ...
};
```

Both will allow the base constructor to be called with the same context (`this`) value.

---

You'll also only want to modify the `prototype` outside of any constructor since its properties and their values will be shared among all instances.

```
var a = new Animal(10);
var b = new Animal(15);
console.log(a.age); // 15 rather than its own 10
```

To set additional properties per-instance, you'll want to instead modify the context `this`:

```
var Animal = function (age) {
    this.age = age;
};

var Pet = function (age, name) {
    Animal.call(this, age);
    this.name = name;
};
```

---

And, regarding `constructor` properties:

The initial `prototype` object will already have the `constructor` property set. So, is isn't usually necessary to set it yourself:

```
Animal.prototype.constructor = Animal;
```

Unless you're replacing the initial `prototype` object completely. For such cases, you'll want to reset the `constructor` afterwards or it'll be set to initial object that's being replaced.

```
Pet.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Pet.prototype.constructor = Pet;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is probably the best answer I've had in days.